# Open Model Brower visual studio 2015 directly

Tags: visual-studio, edmx

I need to open Model Brower  in visual studio 2015 directly without opening EDMX
because it's consuming memory and it's my computer gets slower after opening EDMX
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Model Browser window is a Visual Studio tool window that is integrated with the ADO.NET Entity Data Model Designer (Entity Designer). It provides a tree view of the conceptual and storage models that are defined in an .edmx file

The Model Browser opens when the Entity Designer is opened. If the Model Browser is not visible, right-click the main design surface and select Model Browser.

So without an .edmx file unable to open Model Browser